# Is it possible to scope to object in AngularJs without making a new controller?

Tags: angularjs

I know we can create sub-scopes without making new controllers in angular by simply using ng-repeat.
for example

```
$scope.persons = 
    [
        {id: 0, name: "John"},
        {id: 1, name: "Jack"},
        {id: 2, name: "Jane"}
    ]
```

then

```
<p ng-repeat="person in persons">{{id}} - {{name}}</p>
```

but my question is, can I achieve this scoping result with 1 single object?
For example:

```
$scope.ThePerson = 
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "John",
        badgenumber: 68204,
        // ... etc
    }
```

to then use with:

```
<p ng-should-scope-to="ThePerson">
    {{id}} - {{name}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="badgenumber" />
</p>
```

instead of creating a new controller or having to use "ThePerson.something" on every binding?
Is that possible?

Comment: If the issue is verbosity, you can alias with `ng-init`, assuming the reference you give to the variable doesn't change out from under you:  `ng-init="my_var = foo.bar.baz"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using a very simple directive:

```
app.directive('shouldScopeTo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true, // a new child scope
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            angular.extend(scope, scope.$eval(attrs.shouldScopeTo));
        }
    };
});
```

We create a new child scope, so as not to interfere with the parent scope. Then we extend the new child scope with the given object, making the properties of that object directly available to the scope.

Comment: Wow nice and simple, exactly what I needed.
Tyvm.
Wish I thought of this before.